# Django: Get previous values of a multi-step form to dynamically display the fields of the next step

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I am making a project in Django but Im not using Django built-in forms. Rather, I am using html and bootstrap to render forms. On a page, I want to create a quiz. I am doing this via a multi-step form where I input the number of questions on the first form. Then based upon this field, when I hit next, I want to have the same number of the fields for questions and corresponding answers to appear so that I can set them. For example, if I type 5 questions and hit next, it should have 5 fields for me to enter the questions and each question field should have 4 answer fields. Is there a way to dynamically do this?

Please help :(((( This is very important.

Thank you n here is my code snippet

```
{% block content %}

 <div class="row">
    <h2 style="color: darkblue;" class="text-center">Add a Quiz</h2>
 </div>

<form action="" id="add_test_form" method="POST">
    <!--This form will contain the quiz information-->
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Name of test</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="test_name" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Number of questions</label>
                <input type="number" id="num_qu" class="form-control" name="test_num_questions" min="1" 
              oninput="validity.valid||(value='')" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Time( Duration) in minutes</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="test_duration" min="1" 
          oninput="validity.valid||(value='')" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="button" value="Next" id="first_next" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-10">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


</div>    

<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#first_next").click(function(e){
   var num_of_qu = $("#num_qu").val();
   alert(num_of_qu);
  });
});

</script>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: A form wizard can be used to create multi-step forms https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

Comment: @IainShelvington, what if I want to proceed this way itself? Is there a way??

Comment: Yes you can do  that using jquery/js . But, please show your attempt .

Comment: @Swati, I don't know how to start itself :/

Comment: Start with writing [click event](https://api.jquery.com/click/) on next button and getting [value](https://api.jquery.com/val/) of inputs .

Comment: @Swati, is it good what I've done so far? Do I require only 1 form tag or multiple?

Comment: It depends on you if you need to store values of previous form on next button then use mutliple forms else just one is enough you can save all datas at end to your backend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231813/discussion-between-alpha-and-swati).